# Gulp task isn't running properly when called manually?

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have a gulp task that contains this task:

```
gulp.task("js", function() {
  console.log('Gulp task JS run')
  gulp.src('scripts/*.js')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(include())
      .on('error', console.log)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("public/javascripts"));
});
```

I try to run the task from node like this:

```
        var gulp = require('gulp');
        require('../../gulpfile');

        if (gulp.tasks.js) { 
            console.log('gulpfile contains task!');
            gulp.start('js');
        }
```

And I see "gulpfile contains task" and "Gulp task JS run" in the console, but the it it doesn't seem to actually run, the files are not updated. When running it manually from bash with "gulp js" or from the watch task, it works fine.

Is there any reason this would happen or any way I can troubleshoot it further?

Comment: Not an answer to your question but see https://github.com/wiledal/gulp-include/issues/63 for possible issues when trying to generate sourcemaps with the gulp-include plugin.

Comment: I definitely have that problem. There's no workaround? Is there any alternative?